# windows batch file programming

Tags: batch-file, line, dos

I want to write a line of text at a specific line in an already existing text file using dos batch file programming in Windows XP.Also I want to input the line number from the user. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example of prompting the user:

```
:MENU

    SET /P TYPE=Type the line number and press enter:
    if "%TYPE%"=="1"                               goto ONE
    if "%TYPE%"=="2"                               goto TWO
    if "%TYPE%"=="3"                               goto THREE
    if "%TYPE%"=="4"                               goto FOUR
    if "%TYPE%"=="5"                               goto FIVE
    goto MENU
```

Note: The FOR command with the L option can generate a greater crosscheck;
for more info type c:>FOR /?

FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]

```
The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
```

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,1000) DO if "%TYPE%"=="%%a" goto :VALIDNUM

```
@echo off
rem this only prompts the user for a number

set VALIDNUM=

:MENU
cls
echo.
echo.
If NOT "%VALIDNUM%"=="" echo the number is %VALIDNUM%
echo.

SET /P TYPE=Type a line number and press enter:

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,1000) DO if "%TYPE%"=="%%a" set VALIDNUM=%TYPE%

goto MENU
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you shouldn't be using Batch for this. Or maybe you shouldn't be using batch at all.

Maybe something like this may work. i've not tested it throught.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /a counter=0
echo. > newfile
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (yourfile.txt) do (
    if "!counter!"=="%1" echo "YOUR SPECIFIC LINE" >> newfile
    if not "!counter!"=="%1" echo %%a >> newfile
    set /a counter+=1
)
move newfile yourfile.txt
```

But it won't work if you are using DOS and not a version of Windows NT. (edit your tags if you are using windows and not dos)

Comment: Thanks for the earlier reply.I am using Windows XP. I intend to write a batch file for this. I tried it. But "!" symbol causes error.I want to write a line of text at a specific line in an already existing text file.also i need to input the line no. from user.Now this code clears my existing file. More help?

Comment: Sixth line should be     if NOT "!counter!"=="%1" echo %%a >> newfile

Comment: Yes, i haven't touched batch for a long time. Fixed that. fell free to edit my post for other errors.

Comment: set /a counter+=1
When i checked the value of counter variable it is seen that the above statement is not at all working.The value is not changing in the loop. Thanks in advance...

Comment: How can i replace only an existing line of text with a new line of text in a text file. Is it possible to retain the old line of text also.Is anyone to help me??

Answer (score 2):

User [advanced batch file editor Dr.Batcher](http://www.drbatcher.com), you'll be able to create such scripts just in a few clicks!